# Lambda Calculus function to return TRUE/FALSE without "if"

Tags: python, if-statement, lambda-calculus

*I'm a new comer to Lambda Calculus & trying to understand its workings via Python code.*

---

In Lambda calculus, **TRUE**, **FALSE** & **IFELSE** conditional can be represented as:

*(I'm using L to stand for Lambda symbol)*

```
TRUE = Lx.Ly.x
FALSE = Lx.Ly.y
IFELSE = Lc.Lx.Ly.((c x) y)
```

Using the above definitions, the following hold true:

*(I'm writing the function applications in Python style below)*

```
TRUE(e1)(e2) = e1
FALSE(e1)(e2) = e2
IFELSE(TRUE)(e1)(e2) = e1
IFELSE(FALSE)(e1)(e2) = e2
```

My attempt at creating an Lambda Calculus-style ABS function is coded below in Python. ABS applies the return value from GTZ (Greater-than-zero) repeatedly to compute abs(x).

The GTZ function uses an **if** statement. And since Lambda calculus doesn't have an if statement (AFAIK), how can this be implemented in Lambda calculus?

The online lambda calculus materials I reviewed all mention that IFELSE can be coded as function application; but none of them mention how the conditional input to IFELSE itself can be generated without an "if" statement or equivalent.

Please help me understand how this can be written in Lambda calculus.

Thanks!

```
def TRUE(x):
    def f(y):
        return x   
    return f

def FALSE(x):
    def s(y):
        return y    
    return s

def GTZ(x):
    return TRUE if x > 0 else FALSE

def ABS(x):
    return GTZ(x)(x)(-x)
```

Comment: You could use this: `[FALSE, TRUE][x > 0]`

Comment: If you are trying to use functions for *everything*, you need some sort of functional encoding of integers (or at least natural numbers) upon which you can define `>`.

Comment: (Of course, for natural numbers `GTZ` is really just `NOTZERO`, and it could be trivial depending on your encoding of integers.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. Looks like I need to dig deeper into LC to understand how GTZ can be implemented. Will do further reading for that. Thanks

Comment: http://jwodder.freeshell.org/lambda.html can get you started; it has comparison operators for natural numbers. Integers can be encoded as pairs of natural numbers. Let `ZERO = PAIR NAT_ZERO NAT_ZERO`, `POS_ONE = PAIR NAT_ONE NAT_ZERO`, and `NEG_ONE = PAIR NAT_ZERO NAT_ONE`. (That is, an integer is represented as the difference between two natural numbers. 0 = 0 - 0, 1 = 1-0, -1 = 0 - 1, etc).

Comment: @chepner thanks so much for that link! I'll review that to see how the basic functions are implemented in LC.